# before validation do something, no method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an model for notifications. 
An notification can be posted by an User or an Contact.
and the notification can go to either a business or a notification_area.

people has to be filled, so when there is no user added it has to fill in the Contact that is logged in.

the notification_to has to be filled to so when there is no business added it has to take the latitude and the longitude and add the right area.

I have written the code but it won't work.
First I added it in the controller. But after looking around on google and this site I found I had to add it to the model.

But it still won't work.

What do I do wrong?
I get an error

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :people, :polymorphic => true
   belongs_to :notification_to, :polymorphic => true
   belongs_to :App_of_area
   belongs_to :kind

   before_validation :if_empty_add_the_other

   #validates :photo, presence: true
   validates :message, :status, :people_id, :people_type, :notification_to_id, :notification_to_type, :App_of_area_id, :kinds_id, presence: true


   def if_empty_add_the_other
     unless self.people_type.present?
        self.people = current_contact
     end
     unless self.notification_to_id.present?
        if self.longitude && self.latitude
            @noa = NotificationArea.where( "latitude_A <= #{self.latitude} AND latitude_B >= #{self.latitude} AND longitude_A <= #{self.longitude} AND longitude_B >= #{self.longitude}")
            self.notification_to = @noa.first
         end
       end
     end
   end

end
```

Comment: Where is `create_runner`? Please post both model and controller. And, is that `:App_of_area` correct?

Comment: I added the function" if_empty_add_the_other" to the wrong method, should have been added to Notification. So I added the right code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first you should [DRY](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/getting_started.html#drying-up-the-code) up your code:

```
belongs_to :business
belongs_to :app_of_area
has_many :people, source_type: "Notification"
has_many :api_keys

before_validation :if_empty_add_the_other

has_secure_password 

validates :name, :email, :rights, :password_confirmation, :app_of_area_id, :business_id, presence: true
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
validates :email, uniqueness: true
validates :password, confirmation: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

`:as` is used for polymorphic associations, I believe you want to use `:source_type` as shown above. This would allow you to perform `self.people << current_contact`, but I address this more below.

Why was `:App_of_area` capitalized? Same with `:App_of_area_id`?

Your `if_empty_add_the_other` validation method has a lot wrong with it.

- Use `unless` rather than `if not`.
- Can the two if statements testing latitude and longitude be combined to `if self.longitude && self.latitude`?

You have to ask yourself, how is `current_contact` being passed to this function? Also, you're trying to set `self.people` *equal to* this phantom `current_contact`; `self.people` would contain multiple records, an array if you will, so setting an array equal to an object won't work, hence the `self.people << current_contact` above.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I changed my code above.